# footer position fixed under taskbar nevertheless of <body> content for desktop resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, footer

I want to make my footer be "hidden" under taskbar when page loads nevertheless of my `<body>` content or its size, 
and if page scroll down footer is starting to show up( obviously)...

This "rule" should apply only to desktop resolutions.

Comment: footer first fixed position under taskbar, than if user starrts to scroll down, it starts to be relative, and being shown to him( the user) . sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Is there code or anything else you can give here?  Usually it helps if you post what you have so far and explain exactly where you are stuck

Comment: i am using bootstrap 3, why do you need code, footer must be
$(window).load(function(){
 position:fixed ( under taskbar) 
then if user, starts scrool down , 
position:relative 
// *** all only screen and (min-width: 992px) 
................

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/byw6sk0f/3/

It uses some jquery to show the footer when the user starts scrolling.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
            $('.footer').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.footer').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```